# Deploy Spring Boot application in Tomcat 6 (Traditional deployment)

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, deployment, tomcat6

I trying to deploy a spring boot application (war) in tomcat 6 ( when a deploy in tomcat 7 and older i get no problem ), in fact deploying in tomcat 6 (servlet 2.5) is not possible using **the new way** (i will put the link that describe the new way in the bottom) because Spring Boot uses Servet 3.0 APIs to initialize the ServletContext (register Servlets etc.) so you can’t use the same application out of the box in a Servlet 2.5 container.

the solution to deploy in spring that i found in the documentation (i will put the link in the bottom) is to add web.xml.

Now, when I send a request after deploying i get this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'metricFilter' available
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:327)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:236)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:424)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

I use the same web.xml in the documentation :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>sofadev.docapost.phenix.server.changedot</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And of course the pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>sofadev</groupId>
<artifactId>docapost</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>


<name>docapost</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>sofadev.docapost.phenix.server.changedot.App</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
        <version>3.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId> <artifactId>org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId> 
        <version>1.0.6</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
        <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- marked the embedded servlet container as provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-legacy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**Link for the new way of deployement:**
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_tomcat_deployment.htm

**Link for Traditional deployement (spring documentation):**
https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.2.0.RC1/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going against the Spring Boot requirements by trying to deploy to Tomcat 6. Even if you hack your application to start something might break later. Since you are on Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE [the docs mention it clearly](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.9.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-use-tomcat-7):

> Tomcat 7 & 8.0 work with Spring Boot, but the default is to use Tomcat 8.5. If you cannot use Tomcat 8.5 (for example, because you are using Java 1.6) you will need to change your classpath to reference a different version.

Tomcat 6 is legacy and running it's a security risk. [It's security support ended on 31 December 2016 and you can't download it since 30 March 2017](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-60-eol.html). Upgrade your Tomcat version.

Comment: In our case, we should really deploy in the Tomcat 6. in the second link, they describe how to deploy a WAR in an Old (Servlet 2.5) Container, but I don't know why I get this error.